# How to make QR code with event entry readable on every device?

Tags: calendar, qr-code, adobe-indesign

I require assistance with a QR code that I generated in InDesign for a calendar entry. I designed the QR code with plain text, adding the information "BEGIN:VEVENT" with accompanying data. Unfortunately, my Samsung device only recognizes it as plain text that can be copied. I am planning to invite over 100 people, and it would be beneficial if any device, like the iPhone 11, could successfully scan it. The iPhone 11 appears to handle it without any issues and reads all the data in the calendar app correctly. Thank you.

Functioning QR code with calendar entry on every device that scanns the QR code

Comment: Try the Google Calendar Event Creation URL, then URL-encode (percent encode) the Google Calendar link to make it work for a QR code.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to not store the data inside the QR-Code directly, but in a file, that the QR-Code links to?

This way, you could just embed a URL inside the QR-Code that will redirect to your iCalender File which you would have to upload/host somewhere.